# AngularJs ngmodel , specify ngmodel attribute with spaces

Tags: angularjs

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="History.Pain Legs.Laterality.Right">
```

I want to bind to object have space on the name like Pain Legs, i tried to use
 `ng-model="History['Pain Legs'].Laterality.Right"` it worked if `History['Pain Legs']` has a value but if it does not have value, then  `ngModel` is not creating it and it throws an error: "can not assign value Laterality for undefined". Is this doable?

Comment: Works fine with brackets: http://plnkr.co/edit/Zo2uwP0ikVJoiv4zoh04?p=preview

Comment: It will work in Angular 1.2.22 and later. From changelog: `$parse: correctly assign expressions who's path is undefined and that use brackets notation`

Comment: it seems worked when I updated to Angular 1.2.28 thanks aot.